# Rebind/restart bundles which depend on other one

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

**UPDATED:**

I will like to know if is possible to force all the dependencies which have reference to other `OSGi` Service to unbind to it, for then rebind.

e.g.

I have `A`, `B`, `C` all `OSGi` services which have a service dependency to `X`. Then `X` change something and wants that all other services which are binded to it execute unbind and then bind. This without `X` being stopped or reloaded or change the code of the other services.

Is this possible with standard `OSGi`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing service dependencies and package (type) dependencies.

For service dependencies, when a service is unregistered and a replacement service registered, there are service events which are published. Clients of the service can react which is what Declarative Services, Blueprint and ServiceTracker all help with.

For package dependencies, if a bundle which exports a package is updated, then all dependent bundles which import the package are left wired to the old version of the package. These dependent bundles can be refreshed which will caused them to be stopped, get new class loaders wired to the updated package, and started again. See https://osgi.org/javadoc/r5/core/org/osgi/framework/wiring/FrameworkWiring.html#refreshBundles%28java.util.Collection,%20org.osgi.framework.FrameworkListener...%29.

Comment: You are right I mix up the OSGi services dependencies with the bundle dependencies. But the question stay the same in case of services. I what to force all dependencies which depend on X OSGi Service to unbind and bind again without changing the other components

Comment: You cannot force them to unbind. They need be written to deal with service dynamics and respond to the service events. This is why you use Declarative Services, Blueprint or ServiceTracker when using services.